# Method for splitting linked list with only recursion

Tags: java, recursion, linked-list, divide, divide-and-conquer

I'm having trouble programming a recursive method that will split linked list into sub linked list. I don't want to use any arrays or any types of loops as well.

For example I have a linked like this: [2]->[52]->[23]->[45]->[98]->[10]

I want: [2]->[52]->[23] and [45]->[98]->[10]

Then: [2]->[52] and [23] and  [45]->[98] and [10] and so on.

The code I am using for my linked list is following:

```
public static class ListNode{
    int value;
    ListNode next;
    public ListNode(int value){
        this.value = value;
        this.next = null;
    }
}

public ListNode(int value, ListNode next){
    this.value = value;
    this.next = next;
}

public static int listLength(ListNode node){
    if (node == null)
        return 0;
    return 1 + listLength(node.next);
}
```

I tried doing this but it doesn't seem to work, count is a global I have declared in my class.

```
public static ListNode divide(listNode head){
    listNode left = head;
    listNode right = left;

    if(head == null || head.next == null){
        return null;
    }
    if (count <= listLength(head)/2){
        divide(left.next);
    }
    if (count > listLength(head)/2 && count <= listLength(head)){
        divide(right.next);
    }
    return head;
}
```

Comment: A linked list is really not the appropriate data structure for this. Is this a requirement?

Comment: What is the purpose of the split? You're not doing anything with it, not even returning it. What is your goal?

Comment: Tunaki, unfortunately it is a requirement... its suppose to be like the divide method of a merge sort tree, but with only recursion and no loops.

Comment: in `divide()` your both `left` and `right` point to `head`; I think `right` should be pointing to `head.next`... You also seem to be mixing static (class) members with instance members which can create problems, especially when using `count` as static.